# How to add specific start margin , end margin and margin between items in a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to create a recycler view in which the items spacing should be in below format:

[image]

1. Each row should have 3 items.
2. The left margin of 1st item should be 16dp
3. Margin between each items should be 10dp
4. The right margin of last item should be 16dp
5. The margins are fixed but items should stretch to occupy the width to maintain margins.

How can i add the spacing constraints should grid layout be used or will work for linear too?

Answer (score 0):

**Try following things**

1. In your recycle item use width `match_parent` and give a `10dp` margin to the parent layout. (In your Adaptor Item Layout)
2. In your recycle view provide a `6dp` margin. (In your XML having recycle view)
3. For show items in Grid obviously you need to use `GridLayoutManager` with your Adaptor.

Comment: so you mean 10 dp as start and end margin in item layout (in adapter) and 6 dp start and end margin in recycler view? and will this ensure item view to stretch in width to occupy space?

Comment: It will not stretch, It will manage the width, you need to keep content in center and manage accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a new Java class where you extend `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` like this:

```
public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration
```

The purpose of creating this class is that you can edit the decoration of your adapter's items in your `RecyclerView`.

Then you will declare some `int` variables. These variables will save the last item, the first item, the size of your Adapter's data and the item offset of your items.

```
private int mItemOffset;
private int dataSize;
private int firstItem;
private int lastItem;
```

Well, once you created your class you will make a constructor where you will catch the distance of your items from your main class or whatever the `RecylerView` it's being initialized:

```
public ItemOffsetDecoration(int itemOffset) {
    mItemOffset = itemOffset;
}//close constructor
```

Finally, you will override the `getItemOffsets` method and inside the method you will instantiate the variables explained above.

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                           RecyclerView.State state) {

    dataSize = state.getItemCount();
    firstItem = 0;
    lastItem  = dataSize - 1;

    outRect.set(mItemOffset, mItemOffset, mItemOffset, mItemOffset);

    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == firstItem) {
        outRect.left = 32;
    }
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == lastItem) {
        outRect.right = 32;
    }

}//close method
```

Note that I set all the directions of the items with the `mItemOffset` variable, so this will affect at first all my items, then with some if conditions I used the last and first variable to check if the adapter position is the first and last and if it is true then modify my `outRect` right or left to an specific distance and this will make that in your recycler view the first and the last item will show a different distance with its parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want grid layout manager then your recycler view item will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="@android:string/ok"
            tools:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and your recycler view will be :

```
           <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingHorizontal="11dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="3"
            tools:listitem="@layout/layout" />
```